# Recyclerview with header-image stackfrombottom conditionally

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with a custom first row (header) containing an image and a chatview below.

If I use stackfrombottom and there are many chat messages it works as expected, the last chat item is visible at bottom and scrolling up it scrolls to start of image, like in this image:

[image]

The problem: If there are not many chat messages the image is in the center of the recyclerview (because stacked from bottom) like here:

[image]

Can this problem be fixed without rearranging the header outside of listview? Like in this third image:

[image]

Comment: This can only be done if you implement your own LayoutManager.

Comment: Ok, so lets assume that you have tons of messages in your chat, do you want your header to keep scrolling when you're scrolling your chat or do you want it to be stationary?

Comment: @blipinsk: Keep scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question:

Here I found a tip for item decoration that just takes the header and alters the first row:

[Is it possible to have the last item in a RecyclerView to be docked to the bottom if there is no need to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637693/is-it-possible-to-have-the-last-item-in-a-recyclerview-to-be-docked-to-the-botto)

The code I used with this inspiration:

```
public class StickySummaryDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int childCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    int lastVisibleItemPosition =
            ((LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    int firstVisiblePosition =
            ((LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager())
                    .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    if ((firstVisiblePosition == 0) && (lastVisibleItemPosition == (childCount - 1))) {
        View summaryView = parent.getChildAt(0);
        summaryView.setY(0);
    } else {
        parent.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

And on the recyclerview:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new StickySummaryDecoration(), 0);
```